# How to reach files inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, jsp

i'm trying to to move all my stuff (jsp pages, CSS, images) in the WEB-INF folder.
But now, i can't reach, for example, my CSS with the "usual" code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Style.css" >
```

Under WEB-INF i have this kind of structure

[image]

How can i reach from a JSP page (inside the JSP folder) a CSS file (inside the CSS folder)?

DO i have to use `getServletContext()` in every html page?

Comment: Can we know why do you want to move your resources like CSS and/or images to WEB-INF?

Comment: WEB-INF is a folder that won't be accessed from outside the server. The only files I would move to WEB-INF are jsp fragments - jsp pages that are not intended to be viewable by themselves but only included on other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Do not move HTML resources into WEB-INF, the entire point of that folder is that the server will not directly serve files from there. If you really, really want to, you can but then you must write a controller servlet to serve those static files, don't forget to set the content-type appropriately. Also, you won't be able to access them as "/WEB-INF/css/blah.css" because the server won't serve the folder. So it would be something like "/myServlet?resource=css/blash.css".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring, you can put all your files (CSS,JS,...) in the folder :

`src/main/webapp/resources (create if not exists)`.

And then in your servlet config xml :

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`